# Registry editing using wilcards

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry

Slightly odd one but hoping someone can help...

I am in a predicament where my estate of windows 10 machines keep having an issue with their touchscreens going to sleep. I have tried disabling selective suspend, amending the power plan through registry and GPO edits. Neither have consistently worked. I have found that the only way to remedy the problem is going into device manager and unticking the power management boxes against the usb ports and the device. Now I don't particularly want to do this individually on all 200 machines so I have looked for a scripting solution to try and roll out en masse. The difficulty I have come across is that as the touchscreens have been plugged in to different usb ports and reconnected multiple times they all have different hardware ids associated to them so any solution cannot have a generic guid hardcoded into it. I have isolated the registry keys whose value need to change under control set \ enum and my idea was a batch script which used reg query to identify the subkeys I needed and reg add to amend the values. And this is where I have run into problems! My cmd line is not great, I am learning as I go along so hoping someone could give me some assistance and guidance on what I am doing wrong or where the flaw is in my logic.... I hold my hands up and admit upfront I have butchered other peoples submissions and tried to tweak it to my own purpose but have not succeeded :(

Code is below;

```
@echo OFF
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set REG_KEY="HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB"
set KEY_NAME="SelectiveSuspendEnabled"  
FOR /F “usebackq tokens=5-7 delims=\” %A IN 
(`REG QUERY "%REG_KEY% /v %KEY_NAME% /k2^>nul`) 
    DO (set REG_SUB=%A)
FOR /F ('REG ADD "%REG_KEY%\%REG_SUB%\Device Parameters" /v 
       EnableSelectiveSuspend /t REG_DWORD /d 0')
```

Comment: It would greatly help were you to provide use with a genuine registry key with the value names and data and show us exacly what you intend to add to every one of those keys.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided enough information, *(just some bad code)*, here is a simple command which should identify the registry keys you're hoping to match.

```bat
Reg Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB" /S /F "Device Parameters" /K 2>Nul|FindStr/ILEC:"\Device Parameters"
```

*The above may depend upon your target OS*

Comment: Bad code - ouch! I held my hands up and admitted I was guessing at what I was doing but leadng with that seems a bit mean! Anyway OS is windows 10,I ddi put that bit of info in the post... The reg key I am needing to manipulate are all sub keys of the string you query - so not sure what extra information would be needed.

Comment: Could you at least explain the `SelectiveSuspendEnabled` registry value and it's purpose in your script. You appear to be wanting to add `EnableSelectiveSuspend` with a dword value of `0` to keys which match the output of the line I have provided. Does the `SelectiveSuspendEnabled` value act as an additional filter within the keys my line is outputting?